# Porque no me aparece el objeto boton1 en el Frame?

Tags: java

```
package bienvenidos;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

    public class CapturaDatos {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PantallaCaptura pantalla1=new PantallaCaptura();
            pantalla1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }

    class PantallaCaptura extends JFrame{
            public PantallaCaptura() {
            setTitle("Pantalla de Captura");
                setBounds(400,200,400,400);
                setVisible(true);
                add(new LaminaCaptura());
            }   
    }

     class LaminaCaptura extends JPanel{

        public LaminaCaptura(){
         boton1=new JButton("CapturarDato");
         add(boton1);
         }

         JButton boton1;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `JFrame` `PantallaCaptura` primero se hace visible y después es que se agrega el contenedor con el componente `JButton`, pero como no hay un 'refresh' de la GUI entonces no es posible ver lo que sea se haya agregado (a menos que se re-dimensione el `JFrame`).

Lo que se puede hacer es:

```
setVisible(true);
add(new LaminaCaptura());
revalidate(); //actualiza el árbol de componentes (GUI) y llama a repaint()
```

O en la otra mano, simplemente poner componentes primero y después hacer visible el `JFrame`:

```
add(new LaminaCaptura());
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Johnny, ya quedó